# Proof of the lack of existence of a Hamiltonian Cycle

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Consider a graph of $|V| = 2k+1$ vertices with $k+1$ of those vertices having
exactly degree $2$ such that none of those degree $2$ vertices are adjacent to
each other. I want to go about proving that there does not exist a Hamiltonian
cycle within this graph.

I imagined that we could assume for the sake of contradiction that there
existence a Hamiltonian cycle of length $2k$ in this graph. I would really
like to prove that by pigeon-hole principle, there exists at least two
vertices of degree $2$ that are adjacent to each other, but I am not sure
if it is quite as simple as that. Anyone have recommendations on how to go
about contradicting the existence of the Hamiltonian cycle?

Answer (score 2):

For each degree two vertex, if there exist a Hamiltonian cycle, will contain the two edges adjacent to the vertex.

Since there are $k+1$ vertices of degree two of which none are adjacent, that means there will be $2k+2$ edges you must choose, but a Hamiltonian cycle in a graph of $2k+1$ vertices cannot have that many edges.